# Is there any benefit to Touch-and-Go Deadlifts?

Tags: bodybuilding, strength-training, deadlifts

As per the question title, is there any benefit to doing touch-and-go deadlifts rather than the more "full" reset deadlifts? That is, does the touch-and-go variant provide any specific benefits to training over that of the reset variety?

Comment: I don't think so and I've always considered them rather dangerous.

Comment: The only argument I've heard so far was that they provide "constant tension". Although the touch at the bottom takes away _lots_ of tension, so that never made sense to me.

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla I try to touch *very* gently on touch-and-go. No CrossFit-style bouncing deadlifts here. That helps me maintain plenty of tension.

Comment: This can't be answered accurately without knowing your goals.

Comment: @Ryan - I'm not asking about whether it's specifically of benefit to me. I'm asking if there's any benefit for anybody, relative to "reset" deadlifts.

Answer (score 1):

I find touch-and-go deadlifts useful for accumulating more volume and working higher rep ranges (e.g. 5 to 8) for the purposes of endurance and metabolic stress. Greater care must be taken to maintain back position, and generally I only use this method with weights that I feel quite comfortable with.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of specific benefits over standard deadlifts. You could drop weight on regular deadlifts and achieve the same endurance if that's what you're seeking.

Comment: @Ryan I find that the process of re-gripping and re-setting my back at the bottom, while useful and which I obviously prefer for sets anywhere near maximal, takes too much time for me to get into a good rhythm for endurance or conditioning work. When I'm doing dead-stop sets of 5 at ~350 I find that touch-and-go sets of 8 at just under 300 are quite helpful to train the same muscles without giving them rest. Perhaps I would be better served by back extensions for that purpose? But I'm certainly not going to dead-stop/full-reset my warm-ups at 225.